# Redux with tassign in Angular(typescript) trying to join state.array and action.array but getting state.array.join is not a function?

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, angular-redux

Redux function:

```
  function setAllVideos(state, action) {
    return tassign(state, { allVideos: state.allVideos.join([action.data]) });}
```

Declaration + State:

```
allVideos: Array<Object>;
```

AND

```
allVideos: [],
```

I just can't seem to get the syntax right on joining these together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct should be

```
 return tassign(state, { allVideos: state.allVideos.concat(action.data) });
```